# My grouped Cross bars DON'T dodge, while my Box plots DO

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want my Crossbars to dodge as well, like my boxplots do, in my example it didn't work, any one can explain what i'm doing wrong or fix my code? I used mtcars as an example and included the result as a picture in which my Crossbars DON'T dodge.

```
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$am = factor(mtcars$am)
mtcars$vs = factor(mtcars$vs)

cleanup = theme(
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  panel.background = element_blank(),
  axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
  legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"),
  text = element_text(size = 10))


p = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = am  , y = mpg, colour = vs)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(colour = vs)) +
    stat_summary(aes(colour = vs),
                 fun.data = "mean_cl_normal",
                 geom = "crossbar",
                 position = position_dodge(width = 0.90),
                 width = .2,
                 col = "red")

p + 
  cleanup +
  xlab("AM") +
  ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "VS",
                      values = c("Light Gray", 
                                 "Dark Grey"))
```

Which gave me this Graph:

[image]

Comment: That one pipe (and loading dplyr) is absolutely not necessary for your example. Believe it or not, but there are still people who don't use dplyr.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning! my habits..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is simple: Specifying `col = "red"` overwrites the `aes` mapping to color. There is actually only one group for the crossbars and thus nothing to dodge.

You can fix this by mapping to `group`:

```
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = am  , y = mpg, colour = vs)) +
  #geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(aes(group = vs),
               fun.data = "mean_cl_normal",
               geom = "crossbar",
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
               width = .2,
               col = "red")
```

However, discarding a color scale only for the crossbars obviously doesn't result in a good plot.

Comment: Great, you mean i should use two different colours for the cross bars? i tried 'col = c("orange", "red")', but did not do it.

Comment: You'd need a second color variable, e.g., `aes(color = paste0(vs, 1))` and then specify the additional colors in `scale_color_manual`.